# How to to fix XAMPP after deleting too many MySQL databases?

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I've been stupid enough to delete too many databases in XAMPP with PHPMyAdmin and now my sites on `localhost` don't run properly anymore. Please see this screenshot of the main errors
[image]

I guess entirely reinstalling XAMPP will fix the problem but that might take much more time than necessary. Preferably, I'd like to just reinstall the MySQL component or perhaps recreate/repair some databases required for XAMPP to function properly. However, it looks as if I can only reinstall XAMPP entirely instead of separate components (and if that's correct, it's probably for a reason...).

Do I have a better option here than a complete reinstall of XAMPP?

Comment: Never had this issue. But reinstalling never hurts. Just make sure you backup the stuff you need to keep :-p

Comment: @CaptainCarl: the installation process and tweaking the settings took quite some time (and trial and error). I'll go through that again if necessary but if there's a faster way to get back up and running, I'd prefer that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dropped the database for PHPMyAdmin. If you can just restore that (with a command line mysql tool or any tool that does not rely on a web-interface), you can use phpmyadmin again.

Comment: thank you but where can I find the contents I should insert into this database?

Comment: the database might linger in the installation package. one certainly can't search for it on the web.

Comment: good idea, there seems to be a backup folder in `C:\xampp\mysql\backup`, perhaps I can use that...

Comment: Please explain the process.

Answer (score 12):

OK, fixed it with the kind help of scones.

1) By default (XAMPP 1.8.1 on Windows XP), there seems to be a folder `C:\xampp\mysql\backup\phpmyadmin`. Just copy-paste this entire folder into `C:\xampp\mysql\data`.

2) Stop and restart MySQL

3) If you're using WordPress, your pages may be blank since it may think there are no themes available. Go to `[frontpage url]/wp-admin/`. Now just reactivate the theme you'd like to use and all seems up and running again!

Comment: Stupidly simple. I copied EVERYTHING from my mysql\data folder (which included my databases), and saved them to a "backup databases" folder (not to be confused with the "backup" folder). Then I copied EVERYTHING from the original "mysql\backup" into "mysql\data" folder, and then restarted MySQL from XAMPP> This worked, then I copied each of my databases one-by-one into the mysql\data folder, starting/stopping each time. Little bit of a freak out seeing your mysql database shut down like that!

Comment: that backup folder just fixed everything for me. Thanks so much